# In parallel current sources with capacitors

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, current-measurement, current-source, equation

I have to get the correct equation of multiple parallel non-dependent current source in parallel with capacitors, as i seem to find the correct solution, the resulted simulation in LTSpice shows different results.
Using Millman theorem and considering that $$I_1=I_2=I_3 = 0.000078cos(31.41t)$$ and $$C_1=C_2=C_3 = 45nF$$ i found that $$I_R(t) = I_1/((1/3)+(3(RCw)^2))$$ which gives me **56µA** max at output.

[image: LTspice]

Comment: You can simplify this to one cap and one current source with 3 times the value each.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you configured the sources (i.e. don't hide the values)?

Comment: @tobalt, doing what you suggested is not correct, at least that's what LTSpice has given me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i found that $$I_R(t) = I_1/((1/3)+(3(RCw)^2))$$

There should be a sqrt in the denominator.

I get:

$$
|I_R| = \frac{3|I_1|}{\sqrt{1 + (3RCw)^2}} = \frac{|I_1|}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}+(RCw)^2}}
$$

Plugging in values for \$R\$, \$C\$, \$\omega\$ and \$I_1\$ gives \$|I_R| = 115\,\text{uA}\$.

Answer (score 4):

### Improve your question

As @tobalt mentioned, since this is just an analysis question you can combine the three capacitors, in parallel, and replace them with a simpler construct and you can do the same with the three current sources, as they are oriented so that they add together.

Then this is just an RC impedance tied to a single current source. When writing out your work, it would help a lot if you would *also* point out this observation, as it would save everyone's time having to think that for themselves and then tell you in case you didn't already know it. (I suspect you do know all this. But it never hurts to write more, rather than less, about what you know of a situation.)

So, let's call \$I=3\, I_1\$ and \$C=3\,C_1\$ and \$R=R_1\$. That will help reduce equation clutter without changing the analysis.

### Approach

It appears to me that you are looking for an explanation of the simulation results.

Note that the simulation results are in the time domain. Often, the first thing many of us do is first approach the question by thinking about it in the frequency domain. We could do that, but the only real value would be to work out the frequency at which the impedance is at its maximum. That's not needed since you have the frequency, already. So no need to go there. Besides, ratios in the frequency domain are not the same ratios in the time domain.

All you need to do is work out the reactance of \$C\$ at the given frequency (which appears to be remarkably close to \$f=5\:\text{Hz}\$) and put that in parallel with \$R\$. That will give you a new value and an associated angle.

This avoids any use of frequency domain thinking simply because it really isn't needed here.

Comment: Just in case OP's not convinced: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIDpN.png.

Comment: Isn't the frequency [remarkably] close to 5 Hz?  (31.41 ≅ 5 × 2π)

Comment: @Theodore Yup! Thanks. I made kind of a typo in my calculator! Actually, I got it right once and thought... "remarkably close"... and then later when I typed it in again to get the number, I did it wrong! I'm having one of those days, I guess. Thanks so much for the correction! (The other number I got was for \$f_{_0}\$, which is the frequency where the impedance is at its max. Thinking two ways at once has its hazards.)